# Create a column of height of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a column of of height of parent. I have a `navbar` and below it a `container` with three columns. Now i have to make last right column to height of parent and also `scrollable`. In my case the parent is just the `navbar`.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    // row with three cols
</div>
```

How can i make my third col the height of parent and also scroll able without knowing the parent's heignt?

Comment: The navbar is actually a sibiling, not a parent...

Comment: Can you add a graphic to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I don't have a graphic or more information, the column must have full height of parent div.

Comment: Can you create a graphic in paint or something with colored squares / rectangles to illustrate what you want?  It will help us to visualize your desired output.

Comment: Consider here: http://www.sitepoint.com/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/  Also, here is a quick fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/wv4QQ/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        // row with three cols
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.navbar{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
.container-fluid{
    height: inherit;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

But this assumes that your container-fluid is inside the parent as requested, not outside of it.

Comment: I am happy for you but for A to be the parent of B, B must be inside of A. Else, they are called siblings (as in kids, they have the same horizontal rank)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I assume what you want is for the sidebar to define the height of its parent and for the content to assume the same height. Your markup would look something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sidebar..."></div>
  <div class="content..."></div>
</div>
```

CSS as it is currently supported does allow you to set the height of a child element based on the height of its parent--assuming the parent has a defined height. As others have stated, it does not allow you to set the height of an element relative to its siblings.

You can only get the effect (I think) you want if:

- You are able to set a fixed height on `.parent` and use `height:100%` or `height:inherit` on each of sidebar and content.
- You are able to use JavaScript to dynamically read the height of `.sidebar` and apply it to `.content`.

The CSS solution would look something like this:

```
.parent {
  height: 400px; /* Or 50% or 12em or whatever you want */
}
.aside, .content {
  height: inherit;
}
```

A jQuery solution might look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.content').css('height', $('.sidebar').height() + 'px');
});
```